# StyleGan3 Does not train on my images (assertion error)

Tags: stylegan

I tried a few different things, mainly just resizing the images. But every time it says this:

```
assert list(image.shape) == self.image_shape
```

However, I wrote a program to resize all of the images to 512x512. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?